# ServiceStack update session on heartbeat

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

There is a case in my ServiceStack app that uses `ServerEventsFeature` where I would like to update session\user info during users heartbeats.

The problem is that in the feature a handler for `OnHeartbeatInit` will return a random ID that is not connected to any session in my sessions cache, for example for ONE authenticated client:

```
OnHeartbeatInit = req =>
{
    var userSession = req.GetSession();
    var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(req.GetSessionId());
    //will be XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    var cache = Container.Resolve<ICacheClient>();
    var sessionPattern = IdUtils.CreateUrn<IAuthSession>("");
    var sessionKeys = cache.GetKeysStartingWith(sessionPattern).ToList();
    var allSessions = cache.GetAll<IAuthSession>(sessionKeys);
    var cacheSes = allSessions.FirstOrDefault().Key;
    //will be YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
}
```

So is there any way to update the session\user during heartbeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to update a single session, you can retrieve and update the session with just:

```
OnHeartbeatInit = req =>
{
    var userSession = req.GetSession();
    userSession.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
    req.SaveSession(userSession);
}
```

All the code under:

```
//will be XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
var cache = Container.Resolve<ICacheClient>();
var sessionPattern = IdUtils.CreateUrn<IAuthSession>("");
var sessionKeys = cache.GetKeysStartingWith(sessionPattern).ToList();
var allSessions = cache.GetAll<IAuthSession>(sessionKeys);
var cacheSes = allSessions.FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

Is highly inefficient if you have a lot of user sessions (esp. on every heartbeat) since you're querying and **deserializing all** user sesssions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the code provided is not effective at all, it's in that state for the example. I'm trying to understand why do two keys described in my example differ while they should belong to the same user.

Comment: upd: this code adds a new unauthorized session to sessions cache, still can't get the real session of the user

Comment: @HardLuck It's working for me, check to see that `req.GetSession()` is returning the right user session if it's returning an empty session you have a misconfiguration somewhere, maybe your hosting the server event stream on a different sub/domain and don't have CORS enabled or your saving a [Custom AuthUserSession without DataContract/DataMember attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack). If none of those are the issue then I don't know what is and will need a stand-alone repro to be able to investigate further.

Comment: req.GetSession() does return an empty session with only id and creation date populated, the hosting conditions are 100% ok as it is a self-host local app with close to none custom configs, i believe that some filters may cause such behavior, i will check again. This problem does not reproduce on Service metohds (Post\Get\Any...)